# find the Max and Min with AWK in specific range

Tags: awk, max, min

I have file with three columns , I want to get max of `$3` and min of `$2` but in specific range of `$1` with `awk`:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
==============
X    1    2
X    3    4
Y    5    6
Y    7    8
```

E.g. I want to get the minimum value of `Col2` , and the maximum value of `Col3` while `Col1=X`.

I could handle max and min value but I dont find out how to find it in specific range 
this is my code :

```
awk ' min=="" || $2 < min {min=$2; minline=$0} $3 > max {max=$3; maxline=$0};END {print $1,min,max}'
```

I tried to add `{If ($1==X)}` but It doesnt work well.

Answer (score 3):

```
kent$  echo "X    1    2
X    3    4
Y    5    6
Y    7    8
"|awk '$1=="X"{min=$2<min||min==""?$2:min;max=$3>max||max==""?$3:max}END{print min,max}'
1 4
```

is this what you want?

Comment: Nice one-liner! Would you please explain what the `||min==""?$2:min` part does?

Comment: @massisenergy it is `a = boolean? foo : bar` i.e. `min= (........)? $2: min`

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
awk 'BEGIN { c=1 }
     $1 == "X" { if (c==1) { mmin=$2; mmax=$3 ;c++ }
                 if ($2<mmin) { mmin=$2 }
                 if ($3>mmax) { mmax=$3 }
     } 
     END { print "X min: " mmin ", max: " mmax }' INPUTFILE
```

[See it in action @ Ideone](http://ideone.com/dpvwL).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to collect all the minima and maxima:

```
awk '
  $2 < min[$1] {min[$1] = $2}
  $3 > max[$1] {max[$1] = $3}
  {col1[$1] = 1}
  END {for (c in col1) {print c, min[c], max[c]}}
' file
```